# Open a play store app with a href - HTML

Tags: html, google-play, href

I want to open google play app in a href. This has been asked before, but the solutions did not work. Can you help me?

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=...">
```

Thanks

Comment: The above link would open the play store in the browser. You need to use the `market://details?id=com.example.your.package` link to be able to launch the Google PlayStore app.

Comment: I have the same problem... I am trying to open Google Play App from a href inside a webview. With no Android code treatment inside shouldOverrideUrlLoading method.

Answer (score 3):

You can open the Play Store with following anchor:-

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.your.package" target="_blank" rel="external">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Only works in mobile app..**

```
<a href="market://details?id=com.example.your.package" target="_blank">Click here</a>
```